# How to Root SGH-I717M

Tags: root-access

How to root my device?
(Preferably without requiring the use of Windows OS and preferably not having to delete all files during the process)

Looking though https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184, I did not find any instructions for my particular device.

Here are the details from "About Device" page
(Even though it doesn't say on the page, I should mention it is a Samsung device, not AT&T)

Model Number:

```
SGH-I717M
```

Android Version:

```
4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)
```

Baseband Version:

```
I717MUGMD1
```

Kernel Version:

```
3.0.31-1112295
se.infra@SEP-69 #1
SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 4 15:48:09 KST 2013
```

Build Number:

```
JZO54K.I717MUGMD1
```

Note: As per https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/790, I am allowed to ask this question for a particular device model.

---

What I have tried so far:

KingoRoot (Gives me error 0x148F24)

Comment: Galaxy Note (1st gen)? Such old phones are *very* easy to root - just flash a custom recovery via Odin and flash a compatible SuperSU package.

Comment: BTW, your Samsung Galaxy Note is an AT&T device, the model SGH-I717M was an AT&T specific version of the SGN1. And Andy Yan is correct, rooting this device is quite simple, just use ODIN and flash TWRP, then use it to flash the latest SuperSU package. Or since the device is quite old, look at some custom ROMs, you can easily get KitKat and Lollipop on this device. Look on XDA in the https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-att area, your device name is quincyatt

Comment: Also, official TWRP is fully supported on your device with instructions on how to flash it. https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote1att.html I am pretty sure that the SuperSU bundled in TWRP is sufficient on that device, if you just install TWRP with ODIN, then start it, go to Reboot - System it will prompt you that your device is not rooted and give you an option to install SuperSU that is bundled with TWRP, answer yes and you should be rooted on the next boot, update SuperSU app from the Play Store, then open it and it should prompt you to update the SuperSU binary, do it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried rooting my phone (SGH-I717M) for the first time and was much quicker than I expected (took only 30 minutes).

This preserves all files you currently have (but you should still backup first, just in case)

---

First download latest version of TWRP from https://dl.twrp.me/quincyatt/
(`twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.img` on 2017 05 13)

Change the `img` file into a `tar.md5` by issuing the following:

```
tar -H ustar -c twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.img > twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.tar
md5sum -t twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.tar >> twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.tar
mv twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.tar twrp-3.0.0-0-quincyatt.tar.md5
```

Warning: md5 is sensitive to filenames

Download and run [Odin version 3.09](http://odindownload.com/download/Odin_v3.09.zip) (recommended version by many other websites) on a Windows machine

In Odin, select "AP" under files and choose the `tar.md5` file from earlier

[image: AP]]

In the bottom left, it should say md5 check successful

Select "Start". It should now say "RESET!".
Odin will **APPEAR STUCK** at this point. **WAIT**.
Your device will now automatically boot normally.
WAIT until Odin says "PASS", then close Odin
I had to wait **3 minutes**.

Shutdown your device normally.

Boot into recovery mode and TWRP should now appear.

Select `Reboot` --> `System` and when prompted, select `install SuperSU`

Once your device is on, tap "SuperSU Installer - Tap to install SuperSU and root your device"
Tap install via Google Play Store --> **Update, not Open**

SuperSU should now be installed and should be accessible via `Downloaded Apps`